# Point feature class showing up empty?

Tags: arcpy, point, cursor

After days of solving errors and various issues I finally have code that runs in ArcMap... but the shapefile that shows up does not show any points on the map. I checked the attribute table and all fields are showing up there. Zoom to layer doesn't change anything.

Can anyone help me see why this is happening and how to fix it?

Here is the relevant code that I think is having an issue:
EDIT: adding more code as requested
The name variable is a dictionary from a read/loaded CSV.

```
# Create shapefile
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(arcpy.env.workspace, outputClass, "POINT", "", "", "", coordsys)
# List variables
xCoord = []
yCoord = []
status = []
names = []
pid = 1
# Add fields to new shapefile
arcpy.AddField_management(outputClass, "Name", "TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(outputClass, "Status", "TEXT")

offenseField = ["ID", "Name", "Status", "SHAPE@"]
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outputClass, offenseField) as isCursor:
    for key, values in name.iteritems():
        xCoord.append(values[0][0])
        xCoord = filter(None, xCoord)
        xCoord = map(float, xCoord)
        yCoord.append(values[0][1])
        yCoord = filter(None, yCoord)
        yCoord = map(float, yCoord)
        status.append(values[0][2])
        names.append(key)
    for x, y, z, a in zip(xCoord, yCoord, names, status):
        newPoint = arcpy.point(x,y)
        arcpy.AddMessage("New point saved at {0}".format(newPoint))
        pid = pid + 1
        isCursor.insertRow([pid, z, a, newPoint])
```

Comment: Please show a bit more in your code snippet, specifically the line when you create the insert cursor you are using.

Comment: Edited above to add on more code.

Comment: Is this currently how you have your code indented? In you snippet the second loop is indented in a way that will cause issues

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is. Should the second loop be inside of the first loop? The variables the first loop creates should be saved/accessible to the second loop. What should I fix?

Comment: What is `offenseField` set as? You're inserting 4 values for the row, but it looks like your cursor only has one field. Recommend using `SHAPE@XY` and setting `newPoint = (x,y)` .

Comment: I added the list from above. It's a list with SHAPE@ on it. I thought that was a better way to go than utilizing SHAPE@XY. I will try it with the XY though. EDIT: Changing from using SHAPE@ to SHAPE@@XY has no impact. I suspect it's because I am zipping the lists together. I do not, however, know another way to do this.

Comment: `SHAPE@` expects a geometry object so you would need to construct it with `newPoint = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.point(x,y))`. For troubleshooting, have you tried printing the record you are trying to insert?

`newRow = [pid, z, a, newPoint]`
`print(newRow)`
`isCursor.insertRow(newRow)`